# How to set a title in Cell/Header directory in cakePHP ?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 3.0 and I am using inside the Cell/Header directory a display for the header.

```html
<div id="header">
    <div class="header-title">
        <h2><?php echo (isset($pageTitle)) ? $pageTitle : 'Test'?></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code snippet runs perfectly and on every page. 
I am trying to set the $pageTitle dynamically. This means that I am trying to set it for every page differently. 
I have set inside the UsersController.php

```
$this->set('pageTitle', 'Nebojsa');
```

In index method. 
But when I go to the url /users/index , this page title stays 'test'. 
I have also tried to assign the value inside the Template/Users/index.ctp

```
<?= $this->assign('pageTitle', __('Users')); ?>
```

But it won't work. 
What am I doing wrong ? Could you maybe point me in the right direction, where should I look ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between view templates and layouts you can use:

```
<?= $this->assign('pageTitle', __('Users')); ?>
```

And get the value back in any other template or layout using:

```
<?= $this->fetch('pageTitle') ?>
```

As far as setting the title from the controller your code is correct.

```
$this->set('pageTitle', 'Nebojsa');
<?php echo (isset($pageTitle)) ? $pageTitle : 'Test'?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Jsonras. Could you be more specific ? In their documentation they are being not too specific :-)

Comment: try doing this: replace 

<h2><?php echo  !empty($this->fetch('pageTitle'))  ? $this->fetch('pageTitle')  :  'Test'; ?></h2>.

Then go to your Users Template index.ctp and add <?php $this->assign('pageTitle', __('Users')); ?>

Comment: It doesn't work. I have done every step as you said. I have tried even to add <?php $this->assign('pageTitle', __('Users')); ?> to the view Cell/Header/display.ctp just to see if it works or not and it works :-)
But when I add this line to the Users/index.ctp it just don't work. I don't have the value inside the Cell/Header/display.ctp .

Comment: Try this: go to src/View/Cell/HeaderCell.php find the display function and add this: $this->set('pageTitle','Nebojsa'); This should set the tile for dispaly.ctp. If this does not work maybe you can put your code on Github and I'll check it out.

Comment: Have done that and it doesn't work. This is the github link to my files. https://github.com/Nebojsaa/example

Comment: Everything looks good. Replace the code in display.ctp with <?php echo (isset($pageTitle)) ? $pageTitle : 'Test'?>

Comment: All right. So I need to put the code inside the HeaderCell.php in order to have it out ? Or what is your proposition ?

Comment: Either you can assign the title from the src/Template/Users/index.ctp or through the HeaderCell.php. I usually go to GitHub and try to find a plugin to see how they did it. This should help you: https://github.com/mahmoodr786/icingcms

Comment: I don't know where to find the solution to my problem.. I am going to mark your answer as my answer, because of the will, but I still don't have my solution in place.